# differentiability and continuity in R3

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Prove that if a function is differentiable at $(a,b,c)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ then it is continuous at $(a,b,c)$.

I tried to imitate the proof that if $f$ is differentiable at a specific point in $\mathbb R$ then it is continuous on that point of $\mathbb R$, but I did not know the differentiation formula in $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=(a,b,c)$. By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Total_derivative.2C_total_differential_and_Jacobian_matrix) of derivative we have:

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h\|}{\|h\|}=0$$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then we'll choose small $\delta>0$ that  for $\|h\|<\delta$ we have $\|f(x+h)-f(x)\|<\varepsilon$. There exists $\delta_1>0$ that for $\|h\|<\delta_1$:

$$\frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h\|}{\|h\|}<1$$

(it's by definition of limit) Now let $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\|f'(x)\|})$ and $\|h\|<\delta$ we have:

$$\|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h\|<\|h\|$$

By triangle inequality:

$$\|f(x+h)-f(x)\|-\|f'(x)\|<\|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h\|$$

So:

$$\|f(x+h)-f(x)\|<\|h\|+\|f'(x)h\|\leq \|h\|+\|f'(x)\|\|h\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\|f'(x)\|}(1+\|f'(x)\|)=\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

Let be $x,h\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$
 . If $f$
  is differentiable at the point $x$
 , then there exists a map $\varepsilon$
  on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
  such that $\varepsilon\left(y\right)\rightarrow0$
  when $y\rightarrow0$
  and one can writes$$f\left(x+h\right)=f\left(x\right)+df\left(x\right)\left(h\right)+\left\Vert h\right\Vert \varepsilon\left(h\right).$$
 Now one replaces $h$
  by $th$
  for a real $t>0$
  and gets$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}f\left(x+th\right)=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\left(f\left(x\right)+df\left(x\right)\left(th\right)+\left\Vert th\right\Vert \varepsilon\left(th\right)\right)=f\left(x\right)+\lim_{t\rightarrow0}tdf\left(x\right)\left(h\right)+\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\left|t\right|\left\Vert h\right\Vert \varepsilon\left(th\right)=f\left(x\right)$$
 that is $f$
  is continuous at the point $x$
 . This can be done more generally in any normed vector space. Here, $x=\left(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}\right)$
  and $h=\left(h_{1},h_{2},h_{3}\right)$
 , but this writing is not usefull to answer.

Edit: I used the linearity and the continuity of the map $df\left(x\right)\in\mathcal{L}_{c}\left(\mathbb{R}^{3};F\right)
  $ : for all $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$
  and $h,k\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$
 , $$df\left(x\right)\left(\lambda h+\mu k\right)=\lambda df\left(x\right)\left(h\right)+\mu df\left(x\right)\left(k\right)$$ and $\left\Vert \left|df\left(x\right)\right|\right\Vert <+\infty.
 $